# Upload App From Firebase App Distribution to Google Play Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

**I am searching way for uploading app from [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution) to google play.**

Currently I have implemented GitHub actions where my application automatically push to the firebase app distribution and delivered to testers,

is there any way where I can directly push app from `firebase app distribution` to `google play` ?.

Thanks.

### Git Action

```
name: Deploy Application Manual
on: workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: 
      name: qus
    steps:
      - name: Decode Keystore File
        id: decode_keystore
        uses: timheuer/base64-to-file@v1
        with:
          fileName: 'keystore/keystore.jks'
          encodedString: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE }}
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Build Release Bundle
        run: ./gradlew app:bundleRelease
        env:
          SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS }}
          SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD }}
          SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Upload Build
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Build Artifacts & Save
          path: app/build/outputs/
      - name: Upload Artifact to Firebase Distribution using credential file content
        uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1
        with:
          appId: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID}}
          groups: testers
          releaseNotesFile: README.md
          file: app/build/outputs/bundle/release/App-release.aab
          #serviceCredentialsFileContent: ${{ secrets.CREDENTIAL_FILE_CONTENT }}
          token: ${{secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to post build in different tracks using below script.

---

I have used this actions

https://github.com/r0adkll/upload-google-play

**Action File.yml**

```
name: Deploy Application to Google Play Internal Track
on:
 push:
   tags:
     - "v*"

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: 
          name: '{YOURENVIRONMENT}'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Set Up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11

      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Build Project
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Build Release AAB      // 1
        run: ./gradlew bundleRelease

      - name: Sign AAB               // 2
        uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
        with:
          releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/bundle/release
          signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.KEYSTORE }}
          alias: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS }}
          keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD }}
          keyPassword: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Deploy to Play Store   // 3
        uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1.0.19
        with:
          serviceAccountJsonPlainText: ${{secrets.CREDENTIAL_FILE_CONTENT}}
          packageName: '{YOUPACKAGE}'
          releaseFiles: app/build/outputs/bundle/release/**.aab
          track: internal
          inAppUpdatePriority: 5
          whatsNewDirectory: distribution/whatsnew
          status: completed
```

Comment: what is the best solution you choose for building a CI/CD pipeline in an Android project, especially for the KMP or KMM project?

Comment: I got an `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'distribution/whatsnew'`

Comment: you have to create a directory in project root folder,distribution/whatsnew

Answer (score 1):

Firebase App Distribution makes distributing your apps to **trusted testers painless**. By getting your apps onto testers' devices quickly, you can get feedback early and often. And if you use Crashlytics in your apps, you’ll automatically get stability metrics for all your builds, so you know when you’re ready to ship.

Distribute releases to testers for your Android App Bundle in Google Play. App Distribution integrates with Google Play's **internal app sharing** service to streamline your app testing and launching processes.

Distribute builds using the Firebase console, the Firebase Command Line Interface (CLI) tool, **fastlane**, or Gradle (Android). Automate distribution by integrating the CLI into continuous integration (CI) jobs.

You can distribute to google play using fastline.

Sample tutorial [Link](https://medium.com/@wzieba/github-actions-fastlane-firebase-app-distribution-or-app-center-4fadbdff63f9)

Comment: okay so firebase don't support that kind of feature yet, where we can push our apk file directly to play store.

Comment: Unfortunately it. It needs to be supported with different tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Firebase App provides this feature yet. Probably not the exact answer you were looking for but maybe this can push your in the right direction:

1. What you could do is link your Google Play with your Firebase project (see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-console?apptype=aab).
2. Update build script to publish app bundles through Firebase App Distribution.
3. Update build script to upload the same app bundle on an internal test track in the Play console.
4. Now your app releases should in sync on Firebase App distribution and Google Play and you could promote an app release to production when finished testing.

Comment: So GitHub can only help this time, i have to take support of gitaction & fastlen